# Apache 2.4 .htaccess Set Headers for error pages

Tags: apache-2.4, .htaccess, http-headers

I am setting some headers using .htaccess for a web page, f. e.:

```
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
Header set Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains"
</IfModule>
```

This works fine for usual page access, but the headers are not used on error pages like 404 Not Found and 403 Forbidden.

Is there a way to set Headers for error pages using .htaccess?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ```
> Header set Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains"
> ```

For non-200 OK responses you need to use the `always` *condition*:

```
Header always set Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains"
```

Note that `always` (as opposed to `onsuccess` - the default) refers to the internal table of HTTP response headers, it doesn't necessarily mean that it is *always* set.

Reference:

- https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_headers.html#header